# Url.Action does not work with getJSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following jQuery code in MVC4 **RAZOR** view project.  The call to action method works fine when I hardcode the url. But when I use `Url.Action`, it does not work.

Result from hard code approach: `http://localhost:64994/Search/GetCostpages/?costPageNumber=111`

Result from Url.Action approach: `http://localhost:64994/@Url.Action(%22Search%22,%20%22GetCostpages%22)?costPageNumber=111`

What need to be corrected in this to make it working?

```
$(function ()
{
    $("#btnCostPageNumberMagnifingLens").click(function ()
    {

        var costPageNumber = $("#txtCostPageNumber").val();

        //$.getJSON('/Search/GetCostpages/',{costPageNumber: costPageNumber},

        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Search", "GetCostpages")',{costPageNumber: costPageNumber},
                            function (data) 
                            {

                             alert('Inside Function');

                             });
    });
});
```

Comment: View engine won't process JavaScript files.

Comment: Darin's answer should help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use server side helpers in separate javascript files. You could use the url from your DOM. For example, here you have unobtrusively AJAXified some `btnCostPageNumberMagnifingLens` element.

So you could use an HTML5 data-* attribute on this button to put the desired url:

```
<input type="button" id="btnCostPageNumberMagnifingLens" data-url="@Url.Action("Search", "GetCostpages")" value="some button" />
```

and then in your separate javascript file simply read it from the DOM and use it for your AJAX request:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnCostPageNumberMagnifingLens').click(function () {
        var costPageNumber = $('#txtCostPageNumber').val();
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        $.getJSON(url, { costPageNumber: costPageNumber }, function (data) {
            alert('Inside Function');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. However , is there  a way wihtout using `HTML5` attributes? Currenlty data is coming as `undefined` in my browser.

Comment: Which `data` you are referring to? Is it the argument of your AJAX `success` callback? If so, then this is probably related to your controller action. Is this action being invoked? What does this action return?

Comment: Are you sure that `$(this)` is actual the `<select>` element you have shown? I guess not. The `data-url` attribute is defined on this select element so make sure that you are invoking the `.data()` function on it.

Comment: I am using hidden field approach (mentioned below) since I see it as more un-obtrusive.. Do you see any shortcoming with that?

Comment: Yes, hidden field values have different semantic meaning in HTML. They are supposed to send their values to the server when the form is submitted. So while your solution with hidden values works, it is semantically incorrect markup to store urls in hidden fields because you will never send this value to the server. Quite at the contrary you will use the value of the hidden field to make some AJAX call and send another value to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has no notion of of Url helpers so the `getJSON` method is taking in `@Url.Action("Search", "GetCostpages")` as a string, which is then encoded, resulting in the weird URL you're ending up with.

As long as this script is in the view (not in a separate script file) all you need to do is remove the quotation marks from the `Url.Action` method and razor will know this is a Url helper and not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Darin has pointed out the HTML5 data attribute approach.. That is a good approach

However I am using hidden field approach since I see it as more un-obtrusive..

**jQuery**

```
    var genericUrl = $('.hiddenUrl').val();
    var lastIndex = genericUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    var urlFirstPart = genericUrl.substring(0, lastIndex);

    $("#btnCostPageNumberMagnifingLens").click(function () {

        var url = urlFirstPart + 'GetCostpages/';

    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="loader">
    @Html.Hidden("hiddenUrlName", Url.Action("Action", "Search"), new { @class = "hiddenUrl" })
</div>
```

**Getting App Root - Another Approach**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var appRoot = '@this.Request.ApplicationPath';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you combine view and Js file as on view this method should work.